# unexpected T_STRING - For Loop

Tags: php

I got this error with my paging script. My editor says its on the $active line, but I can't see where it should be tbh.

unexpected T_STRING

```
$current_page = 1;
if(isset($_GET['pagenr']) && is_int($_GET['pagenr'] * 1))
{
        $current_page = $_GET['pagenr'] * 1;
}

$query_count = "SELECT COUNT(thread_id) AS antal FROM forum_thread WHERE fk_sub_category_id = $subid ORDER BY sticky_thread DESC";
$result_count = mysqli_query($con, $query_count);
$row_count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_count);
$threads_in_category = $row_count['antal'];

//Ceil runder op til hele tal.
$total_pages = ceil($threads_in_category / $threads_per_page);


echo "<ul class='pagination'>";

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++)
{ 
    $active = ($current_page == $i ? 'class="active"' : 'class="test"');
    $href = "?page=categories&category_id=$category_id&pagenr=$i"; 
    echo "<li $active><a href='$href'>$i</a></li>"; 
} 
echo '</ul>'; 


//Paging end.
```

Comment: Should I try to pastebin the whole thing?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4TFZSd6q Here :)

Comment: Still no parse error; are you sure it's not the editor at fault?

Comment: its in the browser it say the Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in. And the editor says: Unexpected identifier ''

Comment: And the error points to that file and line number?

Comment: Yes, I think its super wierd

Comment: I think you're looking in the wrong file (or a wrong version of the file).

Comment: Its the correct file,cause if I remove it and echo something it pops in the browser

Comment: If there's a parse error the echo wouldn't show .. so it's unlikely you're looking at the right spot; I would take a step back and reevaluate :)

Comment: If I remove the for loop, and echo something it pops in the browser

Comment: Yeah, well, there's no parse error in the code you've shown so far; maybe some magic hidden chars? :)

Comment: Damn.. I think there is some science going on here.

Comment: What editor are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes please integrate suggestion from Naing Lin Aung and DanFromGermany.

But you can also check for whitespace in your code just before and after script ends

white space
?>
white space

Comment: ALRIGHT. ITS FIXED NOW. THERE WAS A EMPTY SPACE Somewhere on the line between my for loop and my $query.. Now its working ^_^  You are a god man :)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to Naing's post, you should properly concat strings and variables:

```
$active = ($current_page == $i) ? 'class="active"' : 'class="test"';
$href = "?page=categories&category_id=" . $category_id . "&pagenr=" . $i; 
echo "<li " . $active . "><a href='" . $href . "'>" . $i . "</a></li>";
```

Same for the SQL query.
You can put `{$var}` variables in braces but it better (in concern of code highlighting) to simply **never** put variables into quoted strings.

When you put a variable in a string, how should PHP tell when the variable ends?

```
$t = 1;
$te = 2;
$tes = 3;
$test = 4;

// is this $t + estt? or $te + stt ? or $tes + tt ? or $test + t ? or $testt ?
echo "$testt"; 

// spoiler: there is no output at all because it "confuses" PHP
//          ... it also confuses the reader and your editor because it can't
//          do code highlighting correctly on those strings

// correct:


echo $test . 't';
```

Comment: Totally agree. I do not know who came up with the idea to implement such things in PHP...

Comment: Oh okay, will try to do that in the future :) anyways, with ur code, I get  unexpected T_VARIABLE on the $active line

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
$active = ($current_page == $i ? 'class="active"' : 'class="test"');
```

to

```
$active = ($current_page == $i) ? 'class="active"' : 'class="test"';
```

Comment: Not working, same error. Not sure why it says unexpected identifier in my editor..

Comment: just split codes and trace back to where it stop working. When I tested, loop part, It was good

Comment: If I only take the for loop for its self, it happens to. I will drive home now, will be back in 50 minutes to see if someone can help me solv ethis issue :)I

Comment: ALRIGHT. ITS FIXED NOW. THERE WAS A EMPTY SPACE Somewhere on the line between my for loop and my $query.. Now its working ^_^